# Can I mark a SD Card as permanent storage?

Tags: macos, storage, sd-card

I own a PNY - StorEDGE 128GB and I remember that it was initially recognized as a fixed/permanent disk like a hard disk.

I reformatted it to add encryption but now the disk is shown as a removable device. This keeps tools like SkyDrive from using it as a target.

Can I set the volume type somehow?

Answer (score 6):

Yes! You can change the volume from a removable device to a fixed disk by *flipping the removable bit.* Lexar made an application for Windows called '[Lexar BootIt](http://www.getusb.info/flip-your-bit-usb-utility-to-make-local-drive/)', a well known application for this task.

[I found a solution involving DD](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1020293), but ***I have not tested it*** and I'd severely recommend backing up your card before doing ***anything*** with DD/Terminal. I created these instructions quickly. If you aren't comfortable with Terminal, use Windows! ***I am not responsible if your SD card is permenantly damaged in this operation. dd is exceedingly dangerous!***

Use *diskutil list* in a Terminal instance to list all volumes. I found my hard drive under /dev/disk1. Remember to substitute disk1 in the later commands with your own disk name.

Don't forget to unmount the disk:

```
hdiutil eject disk1
```

And now the command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk1 bs=1 count=1
```

Again, back up ***EVERYTHING*** before doing anything with dd!

Comment: I will test today and accept if working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: dd did not work. Will experiment with the Windows Tool tomorrow.

Comment: dd works. You need to unmount (not eject) your sdcard partition and point the dd command to the correct volume (most likely `/dev/disk1` as mentioned in the answer)

Comment: So I tested this on a PCIe attached SSD on osx 10.10 - and it doesn't work.   :(   (and yes, I understand exactly what it's doing, and use dd probably on almost a daily basis...)